# How do I prevent my H1 tag from moving out of sight (dissapearing)?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I haven't done much html and css lately and I can't figure out why my H1 disappears out of sight when I re-size the browser...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <script type="text/javascript src="Jquery1_10_2.js"> </script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap.css" media="screen" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="LogIn_Page.css" media="screen" />
<!--    <script type="text/javascript src="LogIn_Page.js"> </script> -->

</head>
<body>
    <div style="margin-top: 15px;text-align: center;" class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top container">

    <a href="http://somesite.com/" title="Web Site"> <img src="Logo.png" alt="somesite" style="width:225px; height:100px; text-align:center; margin-right:5px"> </a>
    <a href="http://www.somesite2.org/" title="Web Site"> <img src="somesite_logo.png" alt="somesite" style="width:225px; height:100px; text-align:center;margin-right:5px; margin-left:5px;"> </a>
    <a href="http://somesite3.com/" title="somesite Web Site"> <img src="somesite.png" alt="somesite" style="width:225px; height:100px; text-align:center; margin-left:5px;"> </a>

    </div>

    <div class="container body-content" style="margin-top: 125px;">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12"> 
            <H1 style="margin-bottom: 50px;">Welcome to the Crops web application</H1>
            <P>Please login:</P> 

            <button onclick="window.location.href=&quot;/auth&quot;" >Login link</button>

            </div>
        </div>



    </div>



    <div id="footer">

        <footer>
        <script>window.onload = function() {
        var d = new Date();
        var n = d.getFullYear();
        document.getElementById("date").innerHTML = "© " + n + " My company";}</script> 
            <p id="date"></p>
        </footer>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The three images stack on top of each other like they are supposed to, but its just the H1 tag that dispersal totally. I haven't even used any custom css, except for the default bootstrap package.

Could someone point me out to the right solution?

I tried putting inside the H1 tag the following styles: position, float, height, width, min-height, min-width, but none of those seem to work out for me it just keeps disappearing when I size down the browser to the max. Its there when the browser is full screen of course....

Comment: could you please reproduce the issue in a fiddle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `position: relative` to your `navbar`.

```css
.navbar.navbar-inverse {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div style="margin-top: 15px;text-align: center;" class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top container">
  <a href="http://somesite.com/" title="Web Site">
    <img src="Logo.png" alt="somesite" style="width:225px; height:100px; text-align:center; margin-right:5px">
  </a>
  <a href="http://www.somesite2.org/" title="Web Site">
    <img src="somesite_logo.png" alt="somesite" style="width:225px; height:100px; text-align:center;margin-right:5px; margin-left:5px;">
  </a>
  <a href="http://somesite3.com/" title="somesite Web Site">
    <img src="somesite.png" alt="somesite" style="width:225px; height:100px; text-align:center; margin-left:5px;">
  </a>

</div>
<div class="container body-content">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <h1 style="margin-bottom: 50px;">Welcome to the Crops web application</h1>

      <p>Please login:</p>
      <button onclick="window.location.href=&quot;/auth&quot;">Login link</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That was it! Simple and elegant solution. So am I supposed to do put position relative to all divs or?

Comment: You can either place it in a custom stylesheet (so it can work across your app/site) or inline with your navbar class wherever it's needed.

Answer (score 1):

It's not disappearing, it just goes off the screen cause of it's huge size.

Try using `@media (max-width: _px) in CSS to change the position and text size of the`h1` accordingly:

```
@media (max-width:300px){

    h1{
        text-size: _px/em/%;
        <more styles here>
    }

}
```

So when the screen is less than 300px, it'll style the h1 to whatever you put in there.

Answer (score 1):

It's not disappearing, it's just covered by the navbar. You need to add more margin for when the navbar elements stack up and expand the navbar. For example

```
<div class="container body-content" style="margin-top: 300px;">
```

will make it appear. However you need to actually put it in a media query. With your fixed image widths those queries to add to the styles section would be

```
@media (max-width: 732px) {
    .body-content {
        margin-top: 225px !important;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 499px) {
    .body-content {
        margin-top: 325px !important;
    }
}
```